# Ускорение работы рекурсивного метода

Tags: java

Дан метод на Java. Данный метод рекурсивный, выполняет функцию поиска непересекающихся прямоугольников из списков ArrayList.

```
private static boolean mapSeparator(int index, Rect rectangle) {

    boolean isTrue = false;
    int vacationsSize = vacations.size();
    //добавление всех прямоугольников без пересечения
    if (index + 2 < vacationsSize) {
        if (!Vacation.getUniqueRect(rectangle).isEmpty()) { //если есть прямоугольники - сохраняем их, добавляем trueRect
            ArrayList<Rect> middleRects = new ArrayList<>(Vacation.getUniqueRect(rectangle));
            trueRects.add(middleRects.get(0));
            for (Rect middleRect : middleRects) {//закидываем каждый middleRect в следующий шаг
                trueRects.set(index + 1, middleRect);//если из следующей не вернулся прямоугольник - заменяем middleRect
                if (mapSeparator(index + 1, middleRect)) {
                    return true;

                }
            }
            if (!isTrue) {
                trueRects.remove(index + 1);
            }
        } else {
            isTrue = false;//если нет нужных прямоугольников - возвращаем false
        }
    } else if (index + 1 < vacationsSize) {
        if (!Vacation.getUniqueRect(rectangle).isEmpty()) {
            trueRects.add(Vacation.getUniqueRect(rectangle).get(0));
            isTrue = true;
        }
    } else isTrue = true;//если дошли до конца - есть решение, возвращаем true

    return isTrue;
}
```

Суть работы метода: есть первый набор прямоугольников. Из них берется первый, к нему подбираются прямоугольники из второго набора. Далее из полученного набора берется так же первый прямоугольник, к которому идет подбор из третьего и т.д. Если не нашлось нужных прямоугольников из следующего набора - проверяется следующий прямоугольник. Из каждого набора должен вернуться 1 прямоугольник.

Необходимо ускорить работу данного метода. Как это можно сделать? Как вариант - замена рекурсии на итерацию, но как это можно осуществить и можно ли вообще?

Comment: @Forishe если не знаете кол-во итераций - используйте цикл while

Comment: Количество как раз таки известно как `vacationsSize`

Comment: @Ladence дело в том, что в некоторых случаях приходится возвращаться на предыдущий шаг. Добавил описание работы метода в вопрос

Comment: @RomanC vacationSize меняется в зависимости от входных данных. Входные данный представляют собой текстовый файл с наборами прямоугольников. Программа должны работать с разным количеством этих наборов. Программа данную задачу решает в любом случае, но представленный метод ее сильно тормозит

Comment: @Forishe Приведите пример, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему.